# jQuery load html with scripts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron

I've built a super simple app in Electron, I have a nav in index.html and loading content with jQuery .load

The guy I've been building this with wanted to keep it really simple with html and his javascript files. I initially looked at Angular but that was a dead end. As I didn't want to have a load of html pages to update if the navigation changed I decided to go with this.

```
<header>
<nav>
    <a class="home" id="home" href="#/">Home</a>
    <a class="startup" id="startup" href="#">Start Seq</a>
    <a class="faults" id="faults" href="#">Faults</a>
    <a class="engineer" id="engineer" href="#">Engineer</a>
    <a class="help" id="help" href="#">Help</a>
</nav>
</header>
<main id="content"></main>
```

While loading the content with the below:

```
 $(document).on('click', "#startup", function() {
     console.log('startup clicked!')
     $('#content').load('templates/startup.html');
 });
```

In the templates I have some javascript files that need to run on each page. The issue I'm running into is that the scripts keep on running when navigation to another page. Say for example there is a timer in one of the scripts, but when navigating to a different page with a different function that uses the timer, the original timer keeps on running.

Each file that's loaded has something like this inside

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/js/comms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/js/startup.js"></script>
<div> etc....</div>
```

This isn't working either:

```
 $('#startup').click(function() {
      console.log('startup clicked!');
      $("#content").empty();
      $('#content').load('templates/startup.html').hide().fadeIn('fast');
 });
```

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You might back up and describe your overall goal a bit more. This seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Apologies, I'll update the original question